# Connect to Mysql from Chrome extension

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-chrome, localhost

Is it possible to connect to some port on localhost to MySQL and to make SQL queries? 
It's intended as a development tool, so the user authenticates to his own db.

I've found: 
https://npmjs.org/package/mysql-native-pre
plus
http://blog.iceddev.com/2012-11-05-node-js-in-chrome.html

So, it looks like there is a way to run nodeJs in chrome ext. and there is NodeJS module for MySQL communication. 
But that still does not mean, that this particular module will work in Chrome sandbox.

Does anyone have some experience with this? I don't know NodeJS and even Chrome extensions, so before I start digging ...
Thank You.